# Second page = ParentalKey() definition, to use one snippen in different Page models

Tags: wagtail

I defined two `Relationship(Orderable, models.Model)` to be able to use one modelsnippet inside differen Page models like:

```
class GroupstageTournamentModel(models.Model):
...
class GroupstageTournamentRelationship(Orderable, models.Model):
    page = ParentalKey('TournamentPage',
        related_name='groupstage_tournament_relationship')
    match = models.ForeignKey('GroupstageTournamentModel',
        related_name='match_tournament_relationship')
    panels = [
        PageChooserPanel('match')
    ]
class MatchesScreencastRelationship(Orderable, models.Model):
    page = ParentalKey('ScreencastPage',
        related_name='groupstage_screencast_relationship')
    match = models.ForeignKey('GroupstageTournamentModel',
        default="", related_name='match_screen_relationship')
    panels = [
        PageChooserPanel('match')
    ]

class TournamentPage(Page):
    starts_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    ends_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('title'),
        FieldPanel('starts_at'),
        FieldPanel('ends_at'),
        InlinePanel(
            'groupstage_tournament_relationship', label="Group game:",
            panels=None, min_num=1),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class ScreencastPage(Page):

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('title'),
        InlinePanel(
            'groupstage_screencast_relationship', label="Playing First",
            panels=None, max_num=1),
    ]

    parent_page_types = ['home.HomePage']
    subpage_types = []

    def __str__(self):
        # return self.title
        return '{} \n Nächste: {}'.format(self.groupstage_relationship, self.final_phase_relationship)
```

As you can see my idea was to use one of them insite `TournamentPage` and another inside `ScreencastPage`. If i do that this way i get this error:

**ERROR:**

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'id' in class 'GroupstageTournamentRelationship' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'GroupstageTournamentModel'.
```

how can this problem be solved? Is it possible to add somehow the second ParentalKey for relationship with `ScreencastPage` and use it direct inside `GroupstageTournamentModel` like you did in [backerydemo](https://github.com/wagtail/bakerydemo/blob/02710075ae0f2fde272f21f269a55e24a4b339f1/bakerydemo/blog/models.py#L23)?

**UPDATE**

I changed `GroupstageTournamentModel` from `model.Model` to `ClusterableModel` and i changed `related_name` so that it different in both of `related_name`'s 
`related_name='groupstage_tournament_relationship'` and `related_name='groupstage_screencast_relationship'`. I did migrations again and got the same error. Here is my `GroupstageTournamentRelationship` class:

```
class GroupstageTournamentModel(ClusterableModel):
    number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        help_text="Add the unique number of this Match.")
    starts_at = models.DateTimeField()
    # Team 1
    team_1 = models.ForeignKey(
        TeamRooster,
        null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )
    team_1_dress = ColorField(default='#ff0000', blank=True)
    team_1_first_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="")
    # Team 2
    team_2 = models.ForeignKey(
        TeamRooster,
        null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )
    team_2_dress = ColorField(default='#0066ff', blank=True)
    team_2_first_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="")

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('number', classname="6"),
        FieldPanel('starts_at', classname="6"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldRowPanel([
                FieldPanel('team_1', classname="6"),
                FieldPanel('team_1_dress', classname="6"),
                FieldPanel('team_1_first_halftime_score', classname="3"),
            ]),
        ], classname="full", heading="Team 1"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldRowPanel([
                FieldPanel('team_2', classname="6"),
                FieldPanel('team_2_dress', classname="6"),
                FieldPanel('team_2_first_halftime_score', classname="3"),
            ]),
        ], classname="full", heading="Team 2"),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} vs {} {} - {}'.format(self.team_1, self.team_2, self.starts_at, self.number)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Gruppenphase Spiel'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Gruppenphase'
```

**UPDATE**

In migration file i found following, and Im not sure what happens if I remove that:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I shortened the model and added "TournamentPage" for clarity.

Comment: Could you put in the rest of the model definition for GroupstageTournamentModel ? The error seems to point to that model also.

Comment: One idea - try making the related_name different on both relations to the page. ` related_name='groupstage_relationship'` might need to be different.

Comment: (－‸ლ) o m g. I just deleted my migrations and did it again, and all works. I have gone all day to this unfortunately  ˚‧º·(˚ ˃̣̣̥᷄⌓˂̣̣̥᷅ )‧º·˚

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted my migration files included 0001_inicial.py and did again `py manage.py makemigrations` and it all worked !